# How to write State Spaces above, and left of Markov matrix?

Tags: matrices

When we write Markov chain/stochastic matrix, we write the state-spaces above the columns of the matrix and on left hand side of the rows. Can anyone help me with it specially with the case in an equation. We write P = {the transition probability matrix with the state spaces}.
TIA